# Owin authentication sign-out is not invalidating Identity in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin, identity

I am connecting to QBO (Quickbooks Online) app using OAuth. QBO has it's own Auth Server and Auth Client.

I am using single sign-on. So after successfully connecting to QBO I am setting Cookie using following code:

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies");
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
```

My Startup.cs contains:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                LoginPath = new PathString(Paths.LoginPath)

            });
```

To signout I used :

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .Authentication
                .SignOut(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().
                   Select(o => o.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
```

But User.Identity remain valid after sign-out. I have tried different solutions from SO but no success.

Any idea?

Comment: Is `User.Identity` still valid on the next request?

Comment: @kahbazi i noticed cookie is deleted on signout. But identity remain valid. But on refresh identity gets invalidated. I need to redirect to login page just after signout is called. Doesn't signout trigger any middleware?

Comment: How do you determine that Identity is valid?

Comment: After signout call i inspected User.Identity.IsAuthenticated that is true.

Comment: And visually too as invalidated identity cause redirection to login page

Comment: well as you said `signout` just delete the cookie but the User identity still remains on that request. So even after you call `signout` User would not change for that request

Comment: Yep and that's the problem i am facing. Is there any way to redirect for same request?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you call `SignOut` it would delete the cookie in order to invalidate user identity, but the `User` would be still authenticated during that request.

You can put `[Authorize]` attribute on the action that is signing the user out, so it will be redirected to login page.

Comment: In fact my scenario is; i connect to QBO via OAuth and set set identity to authorize mvc controller. Now at some point my qbo session expires and it invalidates the service context that is being used to call qbo REST API, i need when qbo service context expires user redirects to login page,  i am capturing this specific exception on global.asax error handler. N calling signout but i need redirect too.

Comment: I think it's better if you catch and handle exception in MVC filters but if you are in `global.asax` you can use this code to redirect `HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");`

Comment: Yes i am handling server n json exception in custom exception filter class but that do work for controllers only. That exception triggers from cs class that us the helper class to call qbo api.

Comment: in case if we are on  login page itself and redirected by global.asax session timout then we cannot put authorize on login action